# How to use AWS from IronPython

Tags: amazon-web-services, ironpython, boto

How do I got about installing the [boto library](https://github.com/boto/boto) on IronPython so that I can access Amazon web services?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

With 2.7.5, `ipy -X:Frames -m pip install boto` should do the trick to install it. If boto itself doesn't work (which is pretty likely, as I don't think anyone's tried to make boto compatible with IronPython yet) then you should be able to use the [AWS .NET SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/) from IronPython without much difficulty.